# Gradle vs. Maven: Which one is the best option for Android development

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What are the major differences between Gradle and Apache Maven? Why do they benefit in Android applications?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Gradle** is a build **automation system** that uses a **domain-specific** language based on the programming language Groovy.

**Maven** is used for **project build automation** using Java which uses **XML** for its project configuration.

## Maven vs. Gradle

**Fundamental differences**:

- Gradle is based on a graph of task dependencies–in which tasks are the things that do the work.
- Maven is based on a fixed and linear model of phases (clean install package deploy, etc.).

Other differences include build customization ability, dependency vs. directory structure, integrations and user experience.

### Customized builds

In Maven it's easy to find dependencies, but harder to customize the build (in a big project the [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) can be unreadable) than in Gradle.

### Dependency management and directory structure

Maven uses dependency management and Gradle uses the directory structure. Both are clear and easy to maintain.

### Plugins and integrations

There are more available plugins in Maven Central compared to the number of them available for Gradle.

### Performance

Gradel is faster (build, test, etc.)

### User Experience

Maven's longer tenure means that its support through IDEs is better for many users.

Sources:

- [Gradle](https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle/)
- [Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-vs-maven)

Answer (score 8):

As google recommends to use gradle with AndroidStudio I would suggest to stick with that: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/ Back in the days when Android apps where build in eclipse with a plugin provided by google the build system used was ant. I would think that the build process of Android Apps differs enough from the standard Java build cycle it makes sense to use a tool with more expressive capacity then s maven.